# Perl Moose - How do I deploy my class pm file?

Tags: perl, moose

I am trying to look into learning Moose and need to know how to properly deploy my class pm file.

What I mean is I created a Person.pm.

Can I call this in my main package if it is in the same folder as my main.pl script doing a use Person; or do I have to do a make and deploy it to my @INC perl modules location before being able to use the file?

I am hoping to create pm class files in my local folder and then simply call them with my program main.pl in that folder.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: "Can I call this in my main package if it is in the same folder as my main.pl script doing a use Person" - Surely the best way to answer that question is just to try it.

Answer (score 10):

Perl does default to having `.` as the first item in `@INC`, so side-by-side will work. If you want to be a little more sophisticated, you can use `FindBin` and `use lib`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/lib";

# Main program continues...
```

Now put your modules in `lib/` in the same directory as your script, and your script will see them. This keeps your library modules and your script(s) separated. If you're writing tests, you can have a `t/` library with the test scripts starting like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../lib";

use Test::More;
# other test modules, your plan, etc.
```

And your tests will look in the right place for the library modules as well.

You can also use `PERL5OPT=-I/path/to/some/library` to add that path to your `@INC`, and you then don't need `use lib` at all.